# flutter: error while building the project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using a pre-built flutter project and it is giving me the below error.

Please guide to resolve it

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':agora_rtc_engine:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not find native-full-sdk-3.5.2.jar (com.github.agorabuilder:native-full-sdk:3.5.2).

project level gradle file for flutter app

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please show us your  flutter.gradle file. Maybe your configuration file is miss config or something so show us  some flutter configs

Comment: @NyamkhuuBuyanjargal I have added as you asked

Comment: @NyamkhuuBuyanjargal did you commented the gradle: 3.5.2 line? some packages doesn't work with gradle:4.1.0. can you share your flutter pubspec.yaml? it's something in Agora package maybe